# Memory clean up in C: where to check pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

You're creating a struct and you need to destroy it later in your program. However due to some error the struct might actually not have been allocated, so you need to check if the pointer is valid (EDIT: checking for `NULL` doesn't ensure the pointer is valid, see [LucasHenrique's and Giorgi's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29780645/4816097)). Basically you can do this in two ways.

**Check at the 'top':**

main.c:

```
struct my_struct* foo = create();
...
if (foo) {
  destroy(foo);
}
```

mystruct.c:

```
void destroy(struct my_struct* foo) {
  /* Do clean up */
}
```

**Check at the 'bottom':**

main.c:

```
struct my_struct* foo = create();
...
destroy(foo);
```

mystruct.c:

```
void destroy(struct my_struct* foo) {
  if (foo) {
    /* Do clean up */
  }
}
```

The first one makes sure that the user is cleaning up everything correctly, but the second one gives you cleaner code inside main.c (although 'destroy' might not be the best name for that function in that case). I can't really decide which principle I should follow and I'd like to know if there are any real disadvantages to one of them?

Comment: Checking if the pointer isn't null doesn't means that the pointer is valid.

Comment: @LucasHenrique True, maybe I should rephrase that.

Comment: Note that this is a somewhat uncommon problem to try to solve as it's not possible to check if a pointer is valid in the general case.. e.g.  the standard C library doesn't solve it, and if you pass in something invalid to the standard library functions, all bets are off. You could assume/document that any caller should set the pointer to NULL after it's destroyed, and detect a NULL pointer being passed in to your functions.

Answer (score 1):

The `destroy()` function should definitely check whether there is anything to do.

Besides that, less code is needed to be written, compiled, etc. since presumably there are many calls to `destroy()` but only once instance of it.

Note that `destroy()` cannot NULL out the pointer when it is called:

```
foo = create ();
/* use foo a lot */

destroy (foo);

/* No matter what destroy() does, foo is unchanged here */
/* and can be dangerously dereferenced to inspect or modify the object, etc. */
```

Comment: So essentially I should do `foo = destroy(foo)` and return `NULL`?

Comment: @gwj62: That is not a bad idea, but there is nothing to assure the code uses the return value.  Passing the pointer by reference could do a better job.  `destroy(&foo)` and then changing `destroy` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are writing a public library. If you take example of the C library, in most functions you have to pass pointers to valid objects (which a null pointer is not). One exception is the `free` function (similar to a `destroy` function) that allows `free(NULL)` and does a no-operation with such an argument.